# Catalog rules not being applied to some products until the product is saved

Tags: catalog-price-rules, magento-1.6

We have a CE 1.6 site with a lot of products (150,000). All new products are uploaded from a feed. Catalog rules are applied every night via a cron to almost every product. This has all worked fine for quite a long time. However, recently catalog rules stopped being applied to new products unless the product is saved manually.

I have checked that the cron is running the catalog rules apply and also that the scheduled re-indexing is being done. I have also done several manual reindex all. Still the problem persists.

Has anyone come across a similar issue or have a fix for this?

UPDATE:
Found the problem, hope it helps someone else. Turns out that php was running out of memory so increased it in php.ini and all is well again......sometimes it's the simple things...

Comment: Idea: The rule is applied on an attribute which is not imported but set as default, therefore it exists after the save but not before.

Comment: Post your answer, as an answer - then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Just until the OP posts this as his own answer, in case anyone missed it.

> Found the problem, hope it helps someone else. Turns out that php was running out of memory so increased it in php.ini and all is well again